# A Computational Functional Equation Problem: $ f ( x ) f \big( f ( x ) \big) = 1 $

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

How do I approach the following contest problem:

> Let $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a continuous function such that $ f ( x ) f \big( f ( x ) \big) = 1 $. Given that $ f ( 1000 ) = 999 $, compute $ f ( 500 ) $.

Comment: can I ask where you found this from? (personal curiosity, I remember reading it in a pdf somewhere and I've been looking for that pdf ever since, I think it was in a collection of three introductory olympiad problems)

Comment: I found it in an old  introductory handout by Evan Chen here:https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php%3Fid%3DYXR0YWNobWVudHMvNC80Lzg3NzgyZmI1ODE5YWIzOGNkNmE2NTY4NWM4YzA2ODQ0MzUwNjMy%26rn%3DbGVjLnBkZg%3D%3D&ved=2ahUKEwjur-P2p4_jAhXIfSsKHRq1BeYQFjAEegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw08ziP-y7f7biaeNdgyNYbz&cshid=1561832620350

Comment: that was the source! thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Letting $y = f(x)$ in the equation $f(x)f(f(x)) = 1$ we get that for all $y$ in the range of $f(x)$ we have
$$f(y) = {1 \over y}$$
The condition $f(1000) = 999$ implies that $999$ is in the range of $f(x)$, so that 
$$f(999) = {1 \over 999}$$
This implies that ${1 \over 999}$ is in the range too. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem applies and the range of $f(x)$ contains $[1/999, 999]$. In particular it contains $500$, so we have
$$f(500) = {1 \over 500}$$

Comment: Well stated. +1.

Answer (score 0):

$f(500)=\frac1{500}$.

I substituted $1000$ for $x$ into the original equation and found that $999*f(999)=1$, so most logically $f(x)=\frac1x$. In more formal terms, $f(y) = \frac1y$ for all $y \in R.$ To address continuity issues:

$$f(999) = 1/999$$
$$f(1/999) = 999$$

Since $f$ is continuous, it must take on all values between $1/999$ and $999$. So $500 \in f(R).$
$$f(500)=\frac1{500}$$

Comment: $1/x$ is not continuous in $x=0$ and $\frac 1{1000} \ne 999$!.

Comment: $f(x)$ is restricted to input values from $1/999$ to $999.$

Comment: you are right the function restricted to $[\frac 1{999},999]$ but may be you should correct the answer and state that.

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer.